# Tensorflow crash R session [R studio - Ubuntu 18.04]

Tags: r, tensorflow, ubuntu, rstudio

I tried many ways to install tensorflow in R (rstudio) but failed (crash R session). Here are some ways that I tried:

Method 1:

```
install.packages("remotes")
remotes::install_github("rstudio/tensorflow")
library(tensorflow)
install_tensorflow(version = "2.0.0b1")
```

All install successful, but R crash when I run:

```
library(tensorflow)
tf_config() or tf$abs(-1)
```

Method 2:

```
install.packages("devtools")
devtools::install_github("rstudio/tensorflow",dependencies=TRUE)
install_tensorflow()
```

All install successful, but R crash again when I run

```
tf_config() or
tf$constant("Hellow Tensorflow")
```

Method 3:

```
install.packages("tensorflow")
library(tensorflow)
install_tensorflow()
```

When install completed, R crash again when I run:

```
library(tensorflow)
tf$constant("hello tensorflow")
```

Method 4:

```
library(tensorflow)
install_tensorflow(method = "conda", envname = "py3.6", conda_python_version = "3.6")
```

When install completed, R crash again when I run:

```
library(tensorflow)
tf$constant("hello tensorflow")
```

**My environment:**

Ubuntu 18.04

R studio version 1.4.1103

R version 4.0.4

Conda version 4.9.2 (installed anaconda in ubuntu)

Python version 3.8.5

**I see many tensorflow install path in my computer after complete 4 methods above:**

path1: home/user/anaconda3/envs/r-reticulate/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow

path2: home/user/anaconda3/envs/r-reticulate/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow

path3: home/user/anaconda3/envs/py3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow

path4: home/user/anaconda3/envs/py3.8.5/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow

Could you help please ? Thank!